How to structure AlpineAJAX response
I'm trying to build an accordion where all the main categories are listed, and when the user clicks on one, it should expand to display all the subcategories. I have many categories, and each category has many subcategories. Therefore, I believe a solution could be to send an AJAX request when a user clicks on a menu item to retrieve all the subcategories. This approach ensures that the links don't overload the DOM, which is crucial for me.
For this purpose, I want to use AlpineAJAX, but I'm having trouble making it work.
<li x-init @click="$ajax('/subCategories/{{$product->page_id}}', { target: 'subCategories' })">
  <a  href="#">{{$mainCategory->name}}
    <i  class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
       <span class="expand"></span>
  </a>
  <ul id="subCategories"></ul>
</li>

In my example, when the user clicks on the main category label, AJAX requests are sent and the responses arrive. However, instead of the target element being updated, it simply disappears. I'm struggling to figure out why this is happening.
My route:
Route::get('/subCategories/{product}', function (Product $product) {
 $view = view('helloWorld')->render();
 return response()->json(['subCategories' => $view]);
});

And the response:
{
    "subCategories": "<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Hello<\/h1>\n<\/body>\n<\/html>\n"
}

I think the error comes from that I doesn't structure correctly the response, but I can't find an example for Laravel, any help would be appreciate

The response must be a simple HTML string that replaces the target
In your case:

<ul id="subCategories"><h1>Hello</h1></ul>

From your controller (or from your route) you can return that HTML string:
return "<ul id=\"subCategories\"><h1>Hello</h1>\n</ul>\n";


or better a view that contains the same HTML:
return view('hello');

view hello.blade.php:
<ul id="subCategories">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</ul>

